# Android access Webview current url in another class

Tags: android

I have a main activity and `onCreate` method I open a `WebView webView` object with a url.

I have another class `MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService` to handle FCM notification.

I would like to get current webview url in `MyFirebaseMessagingService` class to take action.

How can I access current webview url in `MyFirebaseMessagingService`?

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public WebView webView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       webView = findViewById(R.id.webview);

       WebViewClientImpl webViewClient = new WebViewClientImpl(this, linearLayoutProgressBar);
       webView.setWebViewClient(webViewClient);

       webView.loadUrl(AppConstants.mobileUrl);

    }
}
```

Another class is `MyFirebaseMessagingService`

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
        // How can I access webview.getUrl() here to check current url?
    }
}


public class WebViewClientImpl extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {

        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: is your URL change when user access `AppConstants.mobileUrl`?

Comment: No change in url just wants to access current url. No intent to change webview url just like to know what is current url

Comment: you already load `AppConstants.mobileUrl` if it no changes it still `AppConstants.mobileUrl` right?

Comment: That is only when app is loaded, afterwards url can change when user browse the website.

Comment: got it, could you attach WebViewClientImpl? I will make an answer for you

Comment: @CongHai added the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create class to store current Url

```
public class UrlManager {
    public static String url;
}
```

Update `WebViewClientImpl` class, you should override `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` to get current Url. If you want to make sure `Page` loaded, You can update `Url` inside `onPageFinished`

```
    public class WebViewClientImpl extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
            UrlManager.url = request.getUrl().toString();
            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, request);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {

            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        }
    }
```

In `MyFirebaseMessagingService` you can call `UrlManager.url` to get current `Url`

Comment: How do I access same instance of UrlManager in `MyFirebaseMessagingService`? I tried this but it creates a new instance so `url` is null

Comment: hmm, you call by class name `UrlManager` no need create new instance, this should work when MainActivity already run or you should put default value for it.

Answer (score 0):

in my case, I use `intent.putExtra`.

for example.

in FirebaseMessagingService class,

```
@Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

        Log.d("From: " , remoteMessage.getFrom());

        sendNotification(remoteMessage.getData().get("body"));
    }

    private void sendNotification(String messageBody) {
        Dlog.e("messageBody = " + messageBody);

        try {
            JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject(messageBody);

            int pushType = jsonBody.getJSONObject("data").getInt("pushType");
            String pushTitle = jsonBody.getString("title");
            String textBody = "";
            String contentText = "";
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = null;

                String push_title = jsonBody.getString("title");
                String boardContent = jsonBody.getJSONObject("data").getString("boardContent");
                String boardUrl = jsonBody.getJSONObject("data").getString("boardUrl");

                textBody = boardContent;
                contentText = boardContent;

                if (boardUrl.equals("")){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SplashActivity.class);
                    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                }else {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this, PushWebViewActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("push_title", push_title);
                    intent.putExtra("boardUrl", boardUrl);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                }

            

            Bitmap icon2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

            NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle bigText = new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle();
            bigText.bigText(textBody);

            NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder;
            NotificationManager notificationManager =
                    (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            

            // make Channel for over oreo
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel("channel", "channel_nm", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
                mChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{500, 500, 500, 500});
                mChannel.setLightColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.colorPrimary));
                AudioAttributes att = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                        .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION)
                        .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                        .build();
                mChannel.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
                mChannel.enableVibration(true);
                mChannel.setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION), att);
                notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
                notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), mChannel.getId());
            } else {
                notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext());
            }
            notificationBuilder
                    .setLargeIcon(icon2)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle(pushTitle)
                    .setContentText(contentText)
                    .setStyle(bigText)
                    .setLights(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.colorPrimary), 3000, 3000)
                    .setVibrate(new long[]{500, 500, 500, 500})
                    .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

            int random_num = (int) ((new Date().getTime() / 1000L) % Integer.MAX_VALUE);
            notificationManager.notify(random_num, notificationBuilder.build());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

and in Activity (where you make webview)

```
   boardUrl = getIntent().getStringExtra("boardUrl");
   webView.loadUrl(boardUrl);
```

using from intent.

Comment: I do not want to change url, just wants to access current webview url.

Comment: oh.. you already make code for get current url from webview. right?

Comment: I am testing it now. Have created getter and setter in AppConstants and updating currentUrl data `onPageFinished` method.

Comment: yes. if you want to current url from webview, `onPageFinished ` is what is want to tell.